# Trouble getting table correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

| sy3 | DDT | EXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 000A | 35 |
| 15 | 000B | 40 |
| 16 | 000A | 35 |

I would like it to come out as a pivot table, like this:

| sy3 | DDT | EXT | DDT_EXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 000A | 35 | 000A_35 |
| 15 | 000B | 40 | 000B_40 |
| 16 | 000A | 35 | 000A_35 |

Comment: And that doesn't appear to be a `PIVOT`? You look like you are concatenating 2 columns to create a third?

Comment: Hello, `"I have a table like this"`: this is not a table but text. If you have questions regarding tables then you should provide queries to CREATE the table and INSERT some sample data, instead of attempting to describe the table/data. We cannot use the description directly but we can execute the queries to reproduce the table and data in our server for the sake of the discussion and texts.

Comment: You really need to learn the terms you use before using them! Please go the documentation to learn what PIVOT is since it has nothing to do with your request: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to concatenate some columns to create another column in your `select`. Here is one way

```
select *, concat_ws('_',ddt,ext) as ddt_ext
from t;
```